# How an I trigger a popup before beforeunload confirmation dialog?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to trigger a popup before (or during) the `window.beforeunload` confirmation dialog?

I understand that I can't change the contents of the default browser confirmation dialog but let's say I've written a function that shows my own popup. Can I show that either before or during the browser confirmation dialog?

Let's say I have a component:

```
export MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', e => {
            triggerPopup()
            e.preventDefault()
            e.returnValue = ''
            return null
        })
    }
    ...
}
```

I put a console statement in my `triggerPopup()` function (which shows another React component/modal). It is indeed being called but no popup is shown on the screen. Instead, the default browser confirmation dialog appears and it is only when I click "Cancel" does my popup appear. I would like it to appear before or even at the same time as the default browser dialog. Would it be possible to put a `setTimeout` and delay the triggering of the default browser dialog?

Is that possible?

Comment: Did you see a modal preventing closing like that on any existing website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **you can't**.

The `beforeunload` event is treated by browsers with special care because of tons of JavaScript abuse in the past. The only thing you can do is use `preventDefault()` to cancel unload without user interaction, or return a message string in `returnValue` and let the browser handle interaction. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event).

Your custom popup is not actually a popup, but yet another DOM Element inside your page, so it cannot work like a modal popup created natively by the browser. Because of that you might feel tempted to make the event handler function 'wait' somehow for the user interaction with DOM Element (your custom popup) before returning. Can't be done. JavaScript architecture uses an [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) where each message is processed completely before any other message is processed. So if you try to block you event handler and 'wait', the entire page becomes unresponsive.